# Why do I get an implicit 'any' error on a private getter in my .d.ts files?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-3.6

I upgraded my dependencies via `npm install` or something and now TypeScript 3.6 reports a weird error message

```
Property 'myGetter' implicitly has type 'any', because its get accessor lacks a return type annotation.
```

I don't understand what's happening. My code hasn't changed at all. Moving to TypeScript 3.7 fixes the problem, and TypeScript 3.5, I get the same error along with a new error:

```
An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
```

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading TypeScript to 3.6.5, or ideally a newer version, will fix the issue. Just run

```sh
npm install typescript
```

or if you really need to stay locked to TypeScript 3.6

```sh
npm install typescript@3.6
```

The likely reason why this is happening is that one of your dependencies started using TypeScript 3.7 or newer.

TypeScript 3.7 started generating `get` accessors in `.d.ts` files, but left their types off for `private` members. TypeScript 3.6.4 assumed this was an error under `noImplicitAny`. That's a bug that was fixed in 3.6.5 and TypeScript 3.7.